# How to write test in Cypress for Google translator

Tags: javascript, cypress

Test-case:

pre-conditions: visit https://translate.google.com/

steps:

1. Select English language for left side
2. Select russian language for the right side
3. Enter "Test" on the left
4. Validate all UI

Expected Result: UI appears correctly

My veri bad code in cypress:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('https://translate.google.com/')  
    });

    it('test', function() {
        /* ==== Generated with Cypress Studio ==== */
        cy.get('.aCQag > .kHGNJd > .zXU7Rb > .EO28P > :nth-child(2) > .VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe > .VfPpkd-Bz112c-RLmnJb').click();
        cy.get('.aCQag > .kHGNJd > :nth-child(2) > .bvzp8c > .OoYv6d > .pEyuac > .MeCBDd > .vSUSRc > [jsname="rPx1uf"] > .KKjvXb > .Llmcnf').click();
        cy.get('.aCQag > .kHGNJd > .zXU7Rb > .EO28P > :nth-child(5) > .VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe > .VfPpkd-Bz112c-RLmnJb').click();
        cy.get('.aCQag > .kHGNJd > :nth-child(2) > .bvzp8c > .ykTHSe > .pEyuac > .MeCBDd > .vSUSRc > [jsname="rPx1uf"] > .KKjvXb > .Llmcnf').click();
        cy.get('.er8xn').click();
        cy.get('.Q4iAWc').should('be.visible');
        /* ==== End Cypress Studio ==== */
    });
});
```

It is not work, because locators on this page changes all the time. How can I make it work?

Comment: Yes, those classes are generated and can change whenever they build again. Unfortunately, there is no way for the tests to keep working when the underlying HTML is not under your control.

Comment: Why are you trying to test Google translate to begin with? This seems like a possible XY problem, or maybe a miss-understanding of requirements.

Comment: @DBS Maybe they depend on Google translate as part of their business process and want to ensure that the service is working?

Comment: @JuanMendes I would argue a Cypress test is a terrible way to ensure the uptime of an external service, you'd have to run this test on repeat forever to get any meaningful data out of it.

Comment: @DBS I just have this test case in qa tutorial. I wanted to complete it, but it didn’t work, I thought it wasn’t enough skill.

Comment: @DBS I agree that it's a bad idea, just trying to think of why they may have done it.

Comment: There are a few live websites dedicated for QA automation testing. Also, there are many repos where you can spin up the web app locally and easily test there.